# Require user passwords on linux only on weekdays

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login

Is it possible to make linux require user password only during specified time range, eg. from Monday to Friday? I want to set it this way on my Linux Mint, so that kids cannot access computer on school days without permission, but still allowing to login with password on school days...

EDIT: By login I mean logging in to system using gui

Comment: Please be more specific by what you mean with "require password". Do you want to be able to login graphically without a password? Login on a (remote) shell? Run `sudo` without a password?

Comment: @slhck Edited the question.

Comment: write a script to run on boot, if the day is a weekday, edit the gui config file to allow passwordless auto login. remove that line in a script that runs when gui finishes logging in. it's not as hard as it sounds

Answer (score 2):

This is possible... You make a bash or a programe that change password or disable account for kids on specific day, and than return correct password or account in weekends.

The programe that is responsible for change password or disabeling accounts should be in ~/.xinitrc or some other file that runs before login...

```
if [[ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]] ; then
    //Your programme
fi
```

For additional information check...
  - [Disabling User Accounts](http://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/disabling-user-accounts.html)
  - [Running bash at start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Im running minimal debian with wmii so i put my start up bash in ~/.xinitrc you can chose some other file that run at different run level.

Hope it helps... :)