# Require user passwords on windows on specific time range?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

How can I make Windows ask for user credential on login only on specific days, or any other time range?

*Inspired by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/853173/require-user-passwords-on-linux-only-on-weekdays) only for linux, it give me the same idea because I have similar problem.*

Comment: Ask upon login? For UAC? In which situations exactly?

Comment: I am not aware of any authentication system that works with Windows that would allow this.  What you can do is make the authentication easier but actually require it more often.  For instance a smart card can allow you to do it with a short pin that is require each time the computer is locked.  You can also do biometrics which is built into Windows 8.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I love making ugly hacks to achieve things in Windows, so here's a possible solution :)
I haven't tested it, but it sounds possible.

## 1 - Enable automatic login

[See this article on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/28654/312773) for setting up automatic login in Windows 7. It involves changes in the registry, so be sure to make a backup first. - Also please note, your user must have set a password for the next steps to work.

## 2 - Create a .bat script for locking the computer

Open Notepad and type in the following:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

Save it as **LockDesktop.bat** (name doesn't matter, just an example).

Please note: if it gets saved as **LockDesktop.bat.txt**, you must disable hiding file extensions so you can rename it properly to .bat. Open Windows Explorer, press the **Alt** button, click **Tools** -> **Folder options** -> Switch to the **View** tab -> unmark **Hide extensions for known file types** -> click OK.
Now you should be able to rename it properly to **LockDesktop.bat**

## 3 - Make a Task for automating the lockdown

- Open **Task Scheduler**
- Create Basic Task
- Type "LockDesktop" in the name
- Choose your preferred method for triggering the task, for example daily
- Make necessary changes depending on your previous method for triggering, or leave empty
- Pick **Start a program**
- In the **Program/script:** text field, enter the path to your bat file. For example `C:\LockDesktop.bat`
- Finish

Everytime the task runs, it will run the bat file which basically locks your computer. You will then have to press CTRL+ALT+DEL and enter password to log back in.

Let me know how it goes :)